# Connecting DB25 socket to protoboard/breadboard

Tags: soldering, breadboard, breakout, protoboard

I need to connect a DB25 connector to a breadboard. One way I can think of is buying a solder-cup connector (e.g. http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/171-025-103L001/225ME-ND/858135) and wiring it to the breadboard, but I would like a cleaner and more trusty solution. (e.g. discontinued: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/8552)

Does anyone have experience?

Thanks,
S

Comment: I have no direct experience of that, but DB25 versions of the SparkFun part you mention are available from other manufacturers. Of course, considering how heavy the cable and connector could be, you may want to provide additional physical security by arranging for metal brackets connected to the DB25 socket screws and a base for the breadboard.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the information. I did see some other premade boards with screw terminals. Good to keep in mind as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a short length of ribbon cable to combine a DB25 IDC connector
[image: DB25 IDC Connector]
with a 28-pin IDC DIP socket
[image: IDC DIP Header]

Clamping the IDC parts onto the ribbon cable takes a little care (make sure the 'knives' are correctly lined up over the wires in the ribbon), but I've done it in a small bench vice many times with a better than 99% success rate.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion brhans. I'll be testing this out soon.

Comment: so far it has withstood a quite a bit of dangling and light tugging, but I have strain relieved it with a bit of hot-glue to ensure safety. :)